# does socket.io server need to be seperate from backend when deploying?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am building react app. I have my client folder, and my backend folder that contains all my mongo db models, routes, functions etc...

I know realize that my app needs to use socket.io

My frontend is on localhost:3000 and my backend is on localhost:5000

My understanding is that socket.io needs its own port.

Does this mean when I deploy to heroku I need to deploy a backend server, frontend server, and a socket.io server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is that socket.io needs its own port.

This is incorrect.  socket.io can use the same port as your backend just fine.  Incoming requests to create a socket.io connection can be distinguished from other web requests via a custom header that the underlying webSocket connection protocol uses.  This allows socket.io/webSocket and your http server to use the exact same port.

> Does this mean when I deploy to heroku I need to deploy a backend server, frontend server, and a socket.io server?

No.  You can still just have frontend server and backend server and the backend server can handle both your backend requests and the socket.io connections.

Comment: Thank you jfriend00 for taking the time to explain this. Much appreciated